# Calculated measure per common dimension member

Tags: ssas, sql-server-2016, tabular, ssas-tabular

Given the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [Dimensie].[Cao]
(
    [Cao key] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Cao business key] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK Cao] PRIMARY KEY ([Cao key]),
    CONSTRAINT [UC Cao business key] UNIQUE ([Cao business key])
);

CREATE TABLE [Dimensie].[Datum]
(
    [Datum key] INT NOT NULL,
    [Datum business key] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [Jaar] INT NOT NULL,
    [Maand] INT NOT NULL,
    [Dag van de maand] INT NOT NULL,
    [Datum] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK Datum] PRIMARY KEY ([Datum key]),
    CONSTRAINT [UC Datum business key] UNIQUE ([Datum business key])
);

CREATE TABLE [Personeel].[Contractuele uren]
(
    [Datum key] INT NOT NULL,
    [Cao key] INT NOT NULL,
    [Contractuele uren] NUMERIC(15,6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK Contractuele uren Datum] FOREIGN KEY ([Datum key]) REFERENCES [Dimensie].[Datum] ([Datum key]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK Contractuele uren Cao] FOREIGN KEY ([Cao key]) REFERENCES [Dimensie].[Cao] ([Cao key]),
    CONSTRAINT [UC Contractuele uren] UNIQUE ([Datum key], [Cao key])
);

CREATE TABLE [Personeel].[Werklast uren]
(
    [Datum key] INT NOT NULL,
    [Cao key] INT NOT NULL,
    [Werklast uren] NUMERIC(15,6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK Werklast uren Datum] FOREIGN KEY ([Datum key]) REFERENCES [Dimensie].[Datum] ([Datum key]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK Werklast uren Cao] FOREIGN KEY ([Cao key]) REFERENCES [Dimensie].[Cao] ([Cao key])
);
```

So both tables in the `Personeel` schema are referencing both tables in the `Dimensie` schema.

I have generated a `SSAS tabular` project based on these tables with the following measures:

```
Contracturen := SUM('Contractuele uren'[Contractuele uren])
Uren/FTE     := SUM('Werklast uren'[Werklast uren])
Contract FTE := 'Contractuele uren'[Contracturen]/'Werklast uren'[Uren/FTE]
```

This gives me the following result (`[Dimensie].[Datum].[Maand]` on rows, `[Dimensie].[Cao].[Cao business key]` on columns):

[image]

Which is fine per month. However, the grandtotal is a division of both sums, while I'd like it to be the sum of the subtotals of member `36` and `45`.

How can I change the definition of my measure `Contract FTE` to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an iterator to perform the division at the individual members, before summing up:

```
Contract FTE := 
    SUMX(
        VALUES('Cao'[Cao business key]); 
        DIVIDE('Contractuele uren'[Contracturen]; 'Werklast uren'[Uren/FTE])
    )
```